# How to make the content inside the BarChart horizontally scrollable?

Tags: flutter, dart, bar-chart, fl-chart

I am using the fl_chart package for plotting a graph in my application and I want only the content inside the BarChart to scroll horizontally, instead of wrapping it in a Container and SingleChildScrollView which scrolls the whole BarChart.

[image]

here is the code for the BarChart:

```
SingleChildScrollView(
                            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                            controller: barChartScroller,
                            reverse: true,
                            physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                            child: SizedBox(
                              height: 325,
                              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                              child: BarChart(
                                BarChartData(
                                  titlesData: FlTitlesData(
                                    leftTitles: AxisTitles(
                                      axisNameSize: 30,
                                      axisNameWidget: const Text(
                                        "Glasses",
                                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.teal),
                                      ),
                                      sideTitles: SideTitles(
                                        // showTitles: true,
                                        reservedSize: 40,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    topTitles: AxisTitles(),
                                    bottomTitles: AxisTitles(
                                      sideTitles: SideTitles(
                                        getTitlesWidget: getTitles,
                                        reservedSize: 30,
                                        showTitles: true,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  gridData: FlGridData(
                                      show: true,
                                      drawVerticalLine: true,
                                      drawHorizontalLine: true,
                                      horizontalInterval: 4),
                                
                                  alignment: BarChartAlignment.center,
                                  maxY: 16,
                                  barTouchData: BarTouchData(enabled: true),
                                  barGroups: data
                                      .map(
                                        (d) => BarChartGroupData(
                                          barsSpace: 20,
                                          x: int.parse(
                                            d.date!,
                                          ),
                                          barRods: [
                                            BarChartRodData(
                                              toY: double.parse(d.waterGlass!),
                                              width: 20.0,
                                              color: orange,
                                              borderRadius:
                                                  const BorderRadius.only(
                                                topLeft: Radius.circular(6),
                                                topRight: Radius.circular(6),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                      )
                                      .toList(),
                                ),
                                
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
```

Any sort of help would be kindly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: this question exist already. Please check this link hope it helps you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68421855/how-to-scroll-horizontal-in-a-line-chart-using-fl-chart-in-flutter

Comment: The above question is with reference to line chart and not with bar chart. So kindly reconsider your answer.

Answer (score 0):

One way that I was able to solve this for my code was that I used filtered Lists that were controlled by sliders and Icon buttons to pan and zoom in and out of a list. Basically, you just filter lists cutting off from an index value. This turned out to work very well for my case. Below is some of the logic where the xView is the midpoint of the zoom portion, and the scaleValue is the number of bar charts on each side of the midpoint you want to see. The xView is controlled by a slider, and the scaleView is incremented by plus or minus 1 using icon buttons for zooming in and out. Note that this same filter would have to apply for the y values. It should be the exact same logic, but for the double list.

```js
List<String> getFilteredDates() {
    List<String> output = [];
    int index = 0;
    for (String date in dateList) {
      if (index > xView - scaleValue && index < xView + scaleValue) {
        output.add(date);
      }
      index++;
    }
    return output;
  }
```